# Pointwise convergence for submartingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

If $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space, $(X_n,\mathscr{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a submartingale such that exists a constant $c>0$ with $\left |{X_{n+1}-X_n}\right |<c$. For $\omega \in \Omega$ such that exists a constant $M \in \mathbb{N}$ with $X_n(\omega)<M$ for all $n$, can I say that $X_n(\omega)$ converges? I am trying to analyze question from the Martingale convergence theorem.

Comment: Hint：Since $X_n^+\le M\vee0$ and $\sup_n \mathsf{E}[X_n^+]\le |M|<\infty$, by Doob's convergence theorem of submartingale, $\{X_n,n\ge 1\}$ convergence to an integrable $X_{\infty}$ almost surely.

Comment: But my question is different to applying Doob's convergence theorem. I only know that $X_n(\omega)<M$ for a fixed $\omega$, and not for all.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T:=\inf\{n:X_n\ge M\}$ and use the stopped process $X^T_n:=X_{T\wedge n}$, a submartingale. You can check that $E[(X^T_n)^+]\le M^++c$ for all $n$, so the martingale convergence theorem applies to $X^T$. Finally, notice that $\{X_n<M$ for all $n\}\subset\{T=\infty\}$ and that $\lim_nX_n=\lim_nX^T_n$ on $\{T=\infty\}$.

Comment: To finish: since $M$ was arbitrary, this shows that for any $M$, the limit exists a.s. on the event $\{X_n < M \text{ for all } n\}$.  Hence it exists a.s. on the countable union $\bigcup_{M=1}^\infty \{X_n < M \text{ for all } n\}$.  And your assumption is precisely the statement that this union has probability 1.